# Elasticsearch: remove/update field inside nested object

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

```
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "test",
  "_id" : "1212",
  "_version" : 5,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "count" : 42,
    "list_data" : [ {
      "list_id" : 11,
      "timestamp" : 1469125397
    }, {
      "list_id" : 122,
      "timestamp" : 1469050965
    } ]
  }
}
```

This is my document schema.`list_data` is nested object. I have requirement to update/delete particular filed inside `list_data`. I am able to update `count` field using groovy script.

```
$ curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/index/type/1212/_update?pretty' -d '
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.count = 41"
}'
```

But don't know how to update nested object.

For example i want to add this into `list_data`.

```
{
   "list_id" : 121,
   "timestamp" : 1469050965
}
```

and my document should change to:

```
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "test",
  "_id" : "1212",
  "_version" : 6,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "count" : 41,
    "list_data" : [ {
      "list_id" : 11,
      "timestamp" : 1469125397
    }, {
      "list_id" : 121,
      "timestamp" : 1469050965
    }, {
      "list_id" : 122,
      "timestamp" : 1469050965
    } ]
  }
}
```

and if i perform delete based on `list_id` = 122 my record should look like

```
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "test",
  "_id" : "1212",
  "_version" : 7,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "count" : 41,
    "list_data" : [ {
      "list_id" : 11,
      "timestamp" : 1469125397
    }, {
      "list_id" : 121,
      "timestamp" : 1469050965
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: For add, this may be a better answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42009778/elasticsearch-painless-script-how-to-iterate-in-an-array-of-nested-objects @Priyesh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add a new element to your nested field you can proceed like this:

```
$ curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/index/type/1212/_update?pretty' -d '
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.list_data += newElement",
    "params": {
        "newElement": {
           "list_id" : 121,
           "timestamp" : 1469050965
        }
    }
}'
```

To remove an existing element from your nested field list, you can proceed like this:

```
$ curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/index/type/1212/_update?pretty' -d '
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.list_data.removeAll{it.list_id == remove_id}",
    "params": {
        "remove_id" : 122
    }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Val. Is it supported through Elastic java client ? If you can provide Java client code for same operations that will be great.

Comment: The add method keep adding values even if it's already present. I want to check if `list_id` is already present then only update `timestamp` value otherwise add it. If you can provide some link to learn this script part it will be helpful for me in future.

Comment: You can do it simply by modifying the script with an `if/else` case accordingly.

Comment: @Val how to update list_id's  timestamp for example list_id=121 ?

Comment: @QinDongLiang Your script needs to iterate over the list and find the right one to edit

Comment: @Val thanks  for your answer , but if large amount of nested list data , Update performance is very slow ?

Comment: @QinDongLiang You need to try, as it depends on so many other factors. Feel free to ask a new question about this with your details.

Comment: @Val if nested more than 2 levle's list data , how to curd ?  it likes below ctx._source.one_list_data.two_list_data += newElement is error ?

Comment: @QinDongLiang feel free to create a new question with your exact problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133517/discussion-between-qin-dong-liang-and-val).

Comment: @Val http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41735803/how-to-design-nested-or-parent-child-in-elasticsearch-mapping

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the error `[UpdateRequest] unknown field [params]` as I was using the latest version of ElasticSearch 7.9.0 (When wrote this answer 7.9.0 was the latest), seems like the syntax is changed a bit.

Following should work for newer versions of ElasticSearch:

```
$ curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/<index-name>/_update/1212'
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.list_data.removeIf(list_item -> list_item.list_id == params.remove_id);",
    "params": {
      "remove_id": 122
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but I find that

```
ctx._source.list_data.removeAll{it.list_id == remove_id}
```

can't work. Instead I use `removeIf` like this:

```
ctx._source.list_data.removeIf{list_item -> list_item.list_id == remove_id}
```

where `list_item` could be arbitrary string.

Comment: how we can add multiple conditions over here?

Comment: ctx._source.list_data.removeIf{list_item -> list_item.list_id == remove_id && list_item.list_id != ID012} just a hint.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was the instructions in the following [link](https://iridakos.com/programming/2019/05/02/add-update-delete-elasticsearch-nested-objects). Perhaps it is the version of ES.