# Elasticsearch, how to update a specific nested array field documents which qualify certain criteria?

Tags: arrays, api, elasticsearch, nested, updates

I am fairly new to Elasticsearch:
I have an Elasticsearch mapping designed to accommodate data from highly normalized SQL Server databases. 
I am doing a full load of millions of records every time I have a structural change (mapping change). This would be sometimes so bulky and slow taking days to complete. 
I am trying to find a way to partially update nested array and nested object fields with no need of indexing the whole index data.

this is how my mapping looks like:

```
{
    "Product": {
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "properties": {
            "ProductID": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "ProductCategory": {
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "TotalNumberOfProduct": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "MetalProduct": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "MetalProductCategory": {
                        "index": "not_analyzed",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "MetalProductDescription": {
                        "index": "not_analyzed",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "MetalProductID": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can have multiple multiple MetalProducts nested array documents under a single Product document.
Eg. under ProductID 001 I can have MetalProductID=222 MetalProductID=333. How can I update one specific nested document (MetalProductID=222) under ProductID=001? Thank you for your help.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38741658/elasticsearch-remove-update-field-inside-nested-object/38742217#38742217

Answer (score -1):

You need to _id of the previously inserted document to update it. Elastic search will anyways have to reindex the new data but this time, it can only work within the shard instead of the whole data. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html

Comment: I am explicitly assigning _id always. My question is how you can update a single nested field under that _id mentioning the unique identifier field of the nested object.